Adding Extra Virgin Olive Oil to low fat diet not useful?
In this paper: https://www.ahajournals.org/doi/10.1161/JAHA.124.035034,
"Recipe for Heart Health: A Randomized Crossover Trial on Cardiometabolic Effects of Extra Virgin Olive Oil Within a Whole‐Food Plant‐Based Vegan Diet".
It is highlighted:
"Addition of extra virgin olive oil after consuming low amounts within a whole food, plant‐based diet may impede risk reduction."
Now I am not scientist myself. So I am interested how should I interpret this sentence, and how well is it supported in this paper? Is the data sound enough?
If person is already eating less fat like from cheese and meat, does it mean adding EVOO is not useful or harmful for someone?

@george - I don't have the power to close a question by my single vote. I think the questions are similar (jmo). I'd be pleased to see the question answered.

@george My interpretation of the quote is that adding olive oil to a diet that already contains olive oil may be counter productive. That said, I agree with anongoodnurse that this is a duplicate question. But above all, read the first comment by DoctorWhom on the other question. I fully agree with their comment that the question comes down to a matter of opinion. It's also worth noting that diet and nutrition questions are off topic here unless they're directly related to medical treatment, so this question has three reasons to close and the older one has two.

I'll leave this one open overnight to allow others to weigh in, but both questions can't coexist and both should probably be closed.
